# Windows 10 Upgrade: Stops at 23% without error, Dism not mounting boot.wim WIM Image

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade, dism

I am attempting an OS Upgrade Windows 8.1 Pro -> Windows 10 Pro.

**The Problem**

The installer does not give a message apart from saying that it failed at roughly 23%, opening the setuperr.log, I get this at the end, the first 2 lines seem to point to the problem:

```
2016-07-22 13:23:14, Error                 SP     SPMountWIMCallback: Error mounting/unmouting C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\SafeOS.Mount\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\PendingDeletes\7a3a0cd544a0d101300100002017d421.CbsMsg.dll. GLE [87][gle=0x00000057]
2016-07-22 13:23:24, Error                 SP     CMountWIM::DoExecute: Failed to mount WIM file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\winre.wim. Error 0x80070057[gle=0x00000057]
2016-07-22 13:23:24, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Mount WIM file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\winre.wim, index 1 to C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\SafeOS.Mount. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x000000b7]
﻿2016-07-22 13:23:24, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: ExecuteCurrentOperations reported failure!
2016-07-22 13:23:24, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Using action error code: [0x80070057]
2016-07-22 13:23:24, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImageDeploy::ExecuteRoutine(329): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:25, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Execute(441): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:25, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteAction(3243): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:25, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteActions(3397): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:25, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Execute(1631): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:25, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2024): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:25, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(1987): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:25, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(804): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:25, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(389): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:31, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(232): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-22 13:23:31, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(371): Result = 0x80070057
```

Especially, it seems like the winre.wim image could not be mounted. I don't know what the matching file name in the souce folder is, so I am trying with the 273MB boot.wim.

Mounting this image on the machine I want to upgrade fails.
    DISM.exe /Mount-Image /ImageFile:c:\temp\boot.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\Temp\offline /ReadOnly

Error is reported to be with SetFileSize. There is plenty of free space, also, I checked that the path in total is only 128 chars for that file.

```
2016-07-22 19:52:19, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9648 TID=3564 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
[9648] Caller did not request sparse mount
[9648] Mounting new image.
Wim:         [c:\temp\boot.wim]
Image Index: [1]
Mount Path:  [C:\Temp\o]
[9648] [0xc144012e] 
2016-07-22 19:52:21, Error                 DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=9648 [CreateDestinationFileEx:(5082) -> SetFileSize failed] C:\Temp\o\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-b..d-bootfix.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_de-de_7d99a6b16a9ee7bb\bootfix.bin (HRESULT=0x80070057) - CWimManager::WimProviderMsgLogCallback
[9648] [0x80070057] RestoreFileNodeList:(3490): Falscher Parameter.
[9648] [0xc144012e] 
2016-07-22 19:52:21, Error                 DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=9648 C:\Temp\o\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-b..d-bootfix.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_de-de_7d99a6b16a9ee7bb\bootfix.bin (HRESULT=0x80070057) - CWimManager::WimProviderMsgLogCallback
[9648] [0x80070057] RestoreFilesCallback:(5201): Falscher Parameter.
[9648] [0x80070057] EnumImageDataEntries:(1591): Falscher Parameter.
[9648] [0x80070057] RestoreAllData:(2551): Falscher Parameter.
[9648] [0x80070057] WIMApplyImageInternal:(1189): Falscher Parameter.
[9648] [0x80070057] ImageStubMountDirectory:(296): Falscher Parameter.
[9648] [0x80070057] WIMMountImageHandle:(1061): Falscher Parameter.
2016-07-22 19:52:23, Error                 DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=9648 TID=3564 Failed to mount the image. - CWimImageInfo::Mount(hr:0x80070057)
```

I assume this is the very same error I have with the OS upgrade.

*Falscher Parameter* means *Invalid Parameter*.

**What I have already attempted to fix**

1. Repair System Files

   ```
   sfc /scannow
   DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth && DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
   ```
2. Install the WADK (Assessment and Deployment Kit), launch dism from there
3. Made lots of free space on C:\ drive (200GB)
4. Mount with same syntax and files at same position on 2 other Win 8.1 Pro systems works (German and English versions).
5. Checked date/time settings, currently set to German, I also tried English (. and , swapped)

Error stays the same.

How can I fix the dism/wim in order to allow mounting images again?

Comment: You ran those commands, what was the output, of those commands.  What was in the log files they generated?

Comment: You indicate your upgrade stops without an error, yet you provided documentation, that proves an error is being thrown.  What method are you using to upgrade this machine exactly?

Comment: " don't know what the matching file name in the souce folder is ..." - It's **Sources\SafeOS\winre.wim** per the log file.

Comment: As for your last comment: yes, this is only a temporary source though, that gets generated during installation and deleted before I can look at it (on error). So I am not 100%ly sure. Still, since I also manually cannot mount any wim image on the system, it is likely that the error is with the system configuration.

Comment: As for your 2nd comment: it just says "Update has failed.", it is lacking any details, that is what I meant. For the first question, I can collect everything and upload somewhere, I did not see much information there though, that is why I looked into and pasted the log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you manage to completely install Windows 10, there are 2 times where Setup counts up in percent.

The first time it counts up, before the reboot, it copies the necessary setup files, and round about 23%, it mounts an image using dism/wim.

Looking at the setup logfile, I saw problems with image mounting.

```
2016-07-22 13:23:24, Error                 SP     CMountWIM::DoExecute: Failed to mount WIM file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\winre.wim. Error 0x80070057[gle=0x00000057]
```

In my case, the image mounting mechanism was broken, which I verified by copying Windows_10_pro_de_Upgrade.exctracted.iso\sources\boot.wim from the install source folder to C:\temp and then executing

```
DISM.exe /Mount-Image /ImageFile:c:\temp\boot.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\Temp\offline /ReadOnly
```

to attempt to mount the image, which failed with error code 87. (Folder C:\Temp\offline has to be manually created. Please note that once you successfully mounted the image, you should unmount it again manually via

```
dism /unmount-Wim /MountDir:c:\temp\offline /discard
```

)

I could then compare the behavior on the faulty machine to a Win 8.1 Pro VM I had, where the mounting worked. Looking at the Logfile, I noticed that I got a problem with file

```
Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-b..d-bootfix.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_de-de_7d99a6b16a9ee7bb\bootfix.bin
```

Using [Sysinternal's Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645) I could record dism.exe's actions and compare them to the desired ones. I noticed that the failed action (SetFileSize) occured once in the working mounting case, and twice in the failing one. I looked at the stacktrace of the failing action and saw that there was one additional call, in filter driver cbftlsfs4.sys.

[image: Stacktrace failing operation in Process Monitor]

Some googling revealed that this file belongs to Cloudfogger. Uninstalling Cloudfogger (I moved to viivo some time ago after having different issues with Cloudfogger, so uninstalling was no issue) removed both the filter driver as well as the mounting problem.

The Windows 10 upgrade worked afterwards.

Probably, few people have this exact same issue. On a different machine, with an older version of Cloudfogger, I did not have this issue. For me, it was 2 days of work and investigation, and perhaps this is helpful to someone else, so I wrote down my steps in so much detail.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. This post helped me after weeks of trial and error to get the Anniversary Update installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The dism.exe command has a potential to fix the issue. Look at this thread:

[DISM Restore](http://www.eightforums.com/performance-maintenance/41130-dism-online-restore-health-function-gets-error-0x80240021.html)

As part of the disucssion there are 2 .bat files posted - look at what is inside them and run yourself or use them directly.

However other users report it was not fixable and that they had to reload Win 8.1 - [look here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d126a392-1491-4371-962c-1d1269806aff/win-81-pro-dism-online-cleanupimage-restorehealth-returns-error-14098?forum=w8itprogeneral)

They blame Microsoft (not sure about that) but it might be less time consuming to backup data and install Windows 10 as a fresh copy and use your 8.1 license key to activate

Comment: You can also run the Windows Update troubleshooter. " I looked for "troubleshooter" then "Windows Update". Started the thing... Windows asked to troubleshoot in admin mode... I said yes... Then Windows fixed Windows update (sorry I don't have a screenshot). Then I did restorehealth and 100 % done success!"

Comment: Thanks! Already ran the update troubleshooter several times. It reports it fixes problems but does not improve anything. Also, I already tried the "refresh" install of Win 8.1 that does keep settings and programs, but this fails with similar errors. Will try the different dism options mentioned in the posts, though I think I have tried most already. Also, dism reports it finished successfully on cleanup-image, scanhealth and restorehealth.